# Dataframe filter Null values from list of Columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I've got a `df` like so,

```
ID,A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,123,30,3G,1,123,30,3G
2,456,40,4G,NaN,NaN,NaN,4G
3,789,35,5G,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

I also have a list that has a subset of the header list of df like so,

```
header_list = ["D","E","F","G"]
```

**Now I'd like to get those records from `df` that CONTAINS Null values FOR ALL OF the Column Names in the header_list.**

Expected Output:

```
ID,A,B,C,D,E,F,G
3,789,35,5G,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

I tried, 
`new_df = df[df[header_list].isnull()]` but this throws `error, ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64`

I know I can do something like this,

```
new_df = df[(df['D'].isnull()) & (df['E'].isnull()) & (df['F'].isnull()) & (df['G'].isnull())]
```

But I don't want to hard code it like this. So is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter this with:

```
df[df[header_list].isnull().all(axis=1)]
```

We thus check if a row contains values where `.all()` values are `.isnull()`.

For the given sample input, this gives the expected output:

```
>>> df[df[header_list].isnull().all(axis=1)]
     A   B   C   D   E   F    G
3  789  35  5G NaN NaN NaN  NaN
```

The [**`.all(axis=1)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) will thus return `True` for a row, given all columns for that row are `True`, and `False` otherwise. So for the given sample input, we get:

```
>>> df[header_list]
     D      E     F    G
1  1.0  123.0  30.0   3G
2  NaN    NaN   NaN   4G
3  NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN
>>> df[header_list].isnull()
       D      E      F      G
1  False  False  False  False
2   True   True   True  False
3   True   True   True   True
>>> df[header_list].isnull().all(axis=1)
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```